# Getting my website running on EC2

Tags: web, ssh, amazon-ec2, winscp

I recently signed up for an Amazon EC2 server, and plan to upload my website to an Instance I created.

I prefer to use WinSCP over SSH, but installed PHP, MySql, and httpd on my instance through Putty.

I am having trouble figuring out the next steps to take in order for me to upload my HTML/CSS/Images/PHP files onto the server for use.  I already have my domain pointing to my Elastic IP on my EC2.  Is it now just about creating a public_html folder in my root user/ec2 directory and uploading my site there?

Thanks for any tidbits as I am having trouble finding the resources online.

EDIT:  I also have ElasticFox installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use WinSCP with the same keys you use to authenticate putty. In the session there is a file chooser box entitled "Private key file". Drop the ppk file in there and you'll be able to connect.
See http://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_authentication

In terms of where to put the files, it depends on the flavour of your amazon image. If it's Ubuntu, for example, once you install apache2 (sudo apt-get install apache2), the default web directory is /var/www.

Comment: How do I go about writing to the /www/ folder if I can only connect with ec2-user (ec2 doesn't allow you to login with root)

Comment: Make /var/www owned by ec2-user or create a new user for the web files and make the directory owned by that user. It's your server, you can do anything you want with it, including enabling root logins.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Filezilla client](http://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=client) to upload your files to your EC2 instance using FTP over SSH (SFTP)

Detailed steps [here](http://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Howto) [SFTP using SSH2: Key based authentication ]

Comment: How do I go about writing to the /www/ folder if I can only connect with ec2-user (ec2 doesn't allow you to login with root)